# Call to undefined function create_user()

Tags: php

Very limited programming experience so trying to understand the reasoning behind the following error.

I'm receiving the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `create_user()` in /home/kxxxxxx/www/test_db_functions.php on line 20

db_functions.php

```
<? php
function print_users ($db_con) 
{}
function create_user ($db_con, $Name, $Phone, $Email) 
{}
function delete_user_by_id ($db_con, $ID) 
{}
function delete_user_by_email ($db_con, $Email) 
{}
?>
```

test_db_functions.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test DB Functions</title>

    </head>
    <body>
<?php
require 'db_functions.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli("server name", "username", "password", "db name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
} 

create_user ($mysqli, "Buzz", "0123452, 2buzz@disney.com"); // Am receiving error on this line (Line 20)
create_user ($mysqli, 'Woody', '056789', 'woody@disney.com');
print_users ($mysqli);
delete_user_by_id ($mysqli, 1);
delete_user_by_email ($mysqli, 'woody@disney.com');
print_users ($mysqli);

$mysqli->close();
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wondering if this is part of your actual file code `<? php` with the space in there.

Comment: remove the space `<? php`

Comment: Are both files in the same directory?

Comment: You're also using the wrong variable for connecting in your function. `$db_con` and `$mysqli = new mysqli`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why is it wrong? He's passing the ressource to `$db_con`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois You could be right but it could be a scope issue also.

Comment: `"0123452, 2buzz@disney.com"` is this typo in the original code as well?

Comment: ^ yeah, there it is ^ - I'll blame it on Stack's new layout ;-) so hard to see, everything is so "white" after a while. @kingkero you should make it an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Na, it was my hawk eyes! But even if that is the answer, it would  be "a simple typographical error". However, that should only warn "missing argument"

Comment: This section seems to have been ignored from the get-go anyway (by the OP). @kingkero +1 from me anyway "Hawkeye" ;-) good job.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, wasn't ignoring. I replied to the correct answer just down below. New to the site just getting used to how to function it properly! Thanks for the suggestions everyone. Was a case of typo.

Comment: @ednaaard Kinghero had it *spot on* before the answer was given which would have saved a lot of time for "you". Comments can be just as good as answers ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- will pay more attention to the comments next time, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to Stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here

```
create_user ($mysqli, "Buzz", "0123452, 2buzz@disney.com");
```

Create user expects 4 arguments, but you are giving it only 3, those being

1=$mysqli

2="Buzz"

3="0123452, 2buzz@disney.com"

It cannot find a function with only 3 params, and posts an error.

Answer (score 1):

Check the line:

```
create_user ($mysqli, "Buzz", "0123452, 2buzz@disney.com"); // Am receiving error on this line (Line 20)
```

instead do:

```
create_user ($mysqli, "Buzz", "0123452", "2buzz@disney.com");
```

PHP is looking for the `create_user` function with 3 parameters, your line has a typo that makes the call that way, but you have defined a 4 parameter function.

Comment: If that were the problem, you would get something like `create_user expects 4 params 3 given`. Which will be the next error, but currently the function isn't defined.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the careful eye! There isn't an error anymore so this seems to have done the trick.